# make a timeout widget in android

Tags: java, android, widget

I've been reading about widgets for a few days and I can't figure them out yet. All I got running is a "hello world" widget. 
onUpdate() never worked because of the 30 minutes limit I guess, and I need to update at least ecery 5 minutes.
I read [this article](http://android-er.blogslpot.com.ar/2010/10/app-widget-upsing-alarm-manager.html) and also another one but when the tutorial starts with a clock example I get stuck.
for now all I want to do is refresh with an alarm manager the widget, so it shows say a number
    private static int num =0;
    @Override
    onUpdate(..) {
      remoteView.setText(num); 
      num++;
    }

if anyone could provide me with a simple and working example on how to do this I'd really appreciate it!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna provide u some usefull links that you can focus on:

[How To Code an Android Widget](http://buildmobile.com/how-to-code-an-android-widget/#fbid=hPu_C3byOSj)

[Tutorial – Creating a Custom Analog Clock Widget](http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2009/07/29/tutorial-creating-a-custom-analogclock-widget/)

[Open Source Analog Widget](http://code.google.com/p/open-ahome-clock-widget/)

Comment: very usefull! I've managed to get the widget running thanks to you and the first link, which was quite more clearer than any previous tutorials I've read.